# Related nodes via entity reference connected to an entity reference?

Tags: entities, views

**The Setup:**

Three content types:

1. Lesson Plan
2. School
3. District

Via entity references, "Lesson Plan" nodes reference "School" nodes, and "School" nodes reference "District" nodes.

**The Challenge:**

Construct a Views Block that is shown on "Lesson Plan" node pages that displays other "Lesson Plan" nodes under the same "District" (via the "School").

In other words, show other Lesson Plans from the same District that the current Lesson Plan's School belongs to.

---

I've tried so many combinations of relationships and contextual filters... but nothing seems to work! Help!